# Does the DevExpress Grid work with MVVM and Commands (All I can find are events)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, telerik, devexpress, xceed

I am looking at using the DevExpress WPF Controls.  But it seems that their controls (or the grid at least) use events instead of commands (not MVVM friendly).

I have seen several ways out there to do Event-to-Command conversion.  But they all seem a bit hacked to me.  And I have [read](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/91687.aspx) that they break down when attached to parts of the DevExpress Grid.

I am just getting going on some Blue-Sky development and hacking my UI from the get go seems like a poor idea.

Does the DevExpress Grid work with MVVM and commands? (ie am I missing something?)

If not, does Telerik?  Or any other control venders?

Right now the only one I am seeing that seems to do it is Xceed.  Are they my only option if DevExpress is as limited as it is seeming to be?

Comment: I have found the Dev Express grid is good for viewing, but for CRUD operations it has some deficiences. It's not very MVVM friendly due to lack of built in commands and its missing many events that you would want for full control of CRUD operations. The provided examples are also not that great - very trivial and often use code behind. That said I have also used Telerik and they have patchy support for MVVM also.

Answer (score 1):

Telerik definately works with Commands. However any WPF control can map behaviors to commands by using System.Windows.Interactivity.

Article to paruse
http://www.danharman.net/2011/08/05/binding-wpf-events-to-mvvm-viewmodel-commands/

The important bit is:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
...
<DevExpressControl>    
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>        
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FooCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DevExpressControl>
```

So, in just a couple of xaml lines, you bind an event to a command.

Comment: Events come with arguments. How can I pass the argument of the event to the command?

Comment: Take a look at the link, the article describes exactly how to do so.